# R Error: Error: `f` must be a factor (or character vector)

Tags: r

I'm getting this error:

```
Error: `f` must be a factor (or character vector)
```

Here is the code.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
theme_set(theme_light())

recent_grads <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fivethirtyeight/data/master/college-majors/recent-grads.csv")
head(recent_grads)

# recent_grads <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fivethirtyeight/data/master/college-majors/recent-grads.csv")
majors_processed <- recent_grads %>%
  arrange(desc(Median)) %>%
  mutate(Major = str_to_title(Major),
         Major = fct_reorder(Major, Median))


by_major_category <- majors_processed %>%
  filter(!is.na(Total)) %>%
  group_by(Major_category) %>%
  summarize(Men = sum(Men),
            Women = sum(Women),
            Total = sum(Total),
            MedianSalary = sum(as.numeric(Median * Sample_size)) / sum(Sample_size)) %>%
  mutate(ShareWomen = Women / Total) %>%
  arrange(desc(ShareWomen))



majors_processed %>%
  mutate(Major_category = fct_reorder(Major_category, Median)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Major_category, Median, fill = Major_category)) +
  geom_boxplot()



majors_processed %>%
  arrange(desc(Total)) %>%
  head(20) %>%
  mutate(Major = fct_reorder(Major, Total)) %>%
  gather(Gender, Number, Men, Women) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Major, Number, fill = Gender)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip()


library(ggrepel)
by_major_category %>%
  mutate(Major_category = fct_lump(by_major_category, 6)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(ShareWomen, MedianSalary, color = by_major_category)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = by_mjor_category), force = .2) +
  expand_limits(y = 0)


library(plotly)
g <- majors_processed %>%
  mutate(Major_category = fct_lump(Major_category, 4)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(ShareWomen, Median, color = Major_category, size = Sample_size, label = Major)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(aes(group = 1), method = "lm") +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = percent_format()) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = dollar_format()) +
  expand_limits(y = 0)
ggplotly(g)


library(plotly)
g <- majors_processed %>%
  mutate(Major_category = fct_lump(Major_category, 4)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(ShareWomen, Median, color = Major_category, size = Sample_size, label = Major)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(aes(group = 1), method = "lm") +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = percent_format()) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = dollar_format()) +
  expand_limits(y = 0)
ggplotly(g)


library(broom)
majors_processed %>%
  select(Major, Major_category, Total, ShareWomen, Sample_size, Median) %>%
  add_count(Major_category) %>%
  filter(n >= 10) %>%
  nest(-Major_category) %>%
  mutate(model = map(data, ~ lm(Median ~ ShareWomen, data = ., weights = Sample_size)),
         tidied = map(model, tidy)) %>%
  unnest(tidied) %>%
  filter(term == "ShareWomen") %>%
  arrange(estimate) %>%
  mutate(fdr = p.adjust(p.value, method = "fdr"))

majors_processed %>%
  filter(Sample_size >= 100) %>%
  mutate(IQR = P75th - P25th) %>%
  arrange(desc(IQR))



majors_processed %>%
  ggplot(aes(Sample_size, Median)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(aes(label = Major), check_overlap = TRUE, vjust = 1, hjust = 1) +
  scale_x_log10()

knitr::knit_exit()


# What were the most common *majors*? (Since there were 173, we're not going to show them all).
majors_processed %>%
  mutate(Major = fct_reorder(Major, Total)) %>%
  arrange(desc(Total)) %>%
  head(20) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Major, Total, fill = Major_category)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = comma_format()) +
  labs(x = "",
       y = "Total # of graduates")



majors_processed %>%
  group_by(Major_category) %>%
  summarize(Median = median(Median)) %>%
  mutate(Major_category = fct_reorder(Major_category, Median)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Major_category, Median)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = dollar_format()) +
  coord_flip()


# What are the lowest earning majors?
majors_processed %>%
  filter(Sample_size >= 100) %>%
  tail(20) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Major, Median, color = Major_category)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = P25th, ymax = P75th)) +
  expand_limits(y = 0) +
  coord_flip()
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong here?  I don't even see an 'f' in the code.  I don't see it as a variable, or anything at all.

I'm following the example here.

https://github.com/dgrtwo/data-screencasts/blob/master/college-majors.Rmd

Comment: There's a whole lot of code here. Whittle your post down to just the code where the error occurs i.e. you posted 139 lines of code, but the error occurs on line 46

Comment: At the line where your error occurs, you've got `mutate(Major_category = fct_lump(by_major_category, 6))`. `by_major_category` is the name of your data frame, not your factor column. It's basically a typo. (This is why going through line by line to isolate the problem is helpful for debugging)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your initial error lies inside the function `fct_lump` inside `mutate` inside the code chunk:

```
by_major_category %>%
  mutate(Major_category = fct_lump(by_major_category, 6)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(ShareWomen, MedianSalary, color = by_major_category)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = by_major_category), force = .2) +
### Further, typo below
#  geom_text_repel(aes(label = by_mjor_category), force = .2) +
  expand_limits(y = 0)
```

If you inspect the `fct_lump`:

```
> mutate(Major_category = fct_lump(by_major_category, 6))
Error: `f` must be a factor (or character vector).
> fct_lump(by_major_category, 6)
Error: `f` must be a factor (or character vector).
> ?fct_lump
> # f: A factor (or character vector).
> class(by_major_category)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

`f` is the first parameter passed on to your `fct_lump` function and it is saved in `by_major_category`, but it is not a factor or a character string.

Taking a quick search for the particular code, the correctly formulated chunk uses `Major_category` as `f`:

```
by_major_category %>%
  mutate(Major_category = fct_lump(Major_category, 6)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(ShareWomen, MedianSalary, color = Major_category)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = Major_category), force = .2) +
  expand_limits(y = 0)
```

(Found from the original raw https://github.com/dgrtwo/data-screencasts/blob/master/college-majors.Rmd which your code tries to follow but differs in few crucial spots)

This produces your correct plot. In other words, you should be pointing to the factor in `by_major_category$Major_category` and not its parent data structure.

Deducing from the typo in your code chunk and an odd `knitr::knit_exit()` as well as omitting the text `This is scrap work.` from the linked source, I presume you're manually typing the code from a compiled knitr-document such as a PDF and your errors are due to manual cut-paste / typing. I suggest you refer to the original .Rmd-file, which stands for R Markdown and probably is currently in your use as in HTML/PDF/Word instead of raw R source.

Here is the figure the corrected code chunk should create:

[image: Corrected code chunk]